# Getting issues before a time from github

Tags: github, github-api

The [github issues api](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) provides a way to get all the issues that were updated at or after a particular time, but is there a way I can get all the issues before a particular time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [issues API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) isn't a good fit, you can falbback on the [Issues Search API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues).

That would at least allows to search from oldest to most recent and filter out the ones that are past the time specified initially.

> Example
>
> Let’s say you want to find the oldest unresolved Python bugs on Windows. Your query might look something like this.

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=windows+label:bug+language:python+state:open&sort=created&order=asc
```

Filter the result of that query and what is left is all the issues *before* a certain date.

Comment: Thanks. This helps but I wanted to query by timestamp and should be able to figure out a workaround.

Comment: So can I assume there isn't a direct way, as of now, to get issues before a particular timestamp?

Comment: You get the timestamp in the search results, but there doesn't seem indeed to be a direct way to query by timestamps.

Comment: Github's search issues api should do it though not in a clean way.